# Jquery - resize font

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a menu like this : http://www.citrus7.com.br/
I've tried with textfit plugin to resize the font when i resize the window, but i cant resize each line of the menu separately.
Can anyone help me, or point me in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: Show us the code you have written sofar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are each of your lines in a separate element? You'll have to set each line in its own element in order for their sizes to be set individually.

```
<h1 class="headerLine">LEMONS</h1>
<h1 class="headerLine">LEMONADE</h1>
<h1 class="headerLine">SOMETHING ABOUT CITRUS</h1>
```

Assuming that you're using [jQuery.fittext](http://fittextjs.com/) you should be able to run it against all of them with one selector.

```
$(".headerLine").fittext();
```

Comment: Really? Looking at the source it's [nested within the each](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js/blob/master/jquery.fittext.js#L16) and should evaluate them seperately unless you're passing a `kompressor` argument. Maybe my understanding of the plugin is wrong.

Comment: Okay, getting that completely wrong made me angry. Here's a working version I just hacked from scratch. http://jsfiddle.net/whatgoodisaroad/nQBYG/1/

Comment: I made a version with fittext, but i can't find a way to fit the window. [http://jsfiddle.net/EdSbr/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/EdSbr/2/)